# How to reuse a single literal value to initialize multiple different types in a XAML resource dictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Many types in XAML have converters that accept identical format inputs, but the types themselves are not implicitly compatible. For instance "0:0:4" can be a Duration or a Keytime among many others. And sometimes I'd like to use the same value for these sort of things. For instance perhaps I have a KeyTime that starts right after the Duration of another animation:

```
<Duration x:Key="Foo">0:0:4</Duration>
<KeyTime x:Key="Bar">0:0:4</KeyTime>
```

The problem with this is that there's no way to express the contract that these values should be the same. So what I'd like is something along the lines of:

```
<system:String x:Key="AnimationTime">0:0:4</system:String>
<Duration x:Key="Foo">[AnimationTime]</Duration>
<KeyTime x:Key="Bar">[AnimationTime]</KeyTime>
```

But I'm uncertain of the syntax for this. I assume I need to invoke the converters for the Duration/Keytime but I'm finding XAML syntax is not always the most intuitive.

Comment: Duration has a timespan ctor. Keytime is set from a timespan. So I'd try defining a timespan resource rather than string and reference it by staticresource.

Comment: No go there unfortunately. Got exceptions across all efforts along the lines of: ArgumentException: '00:00:04' is not a valid value for property 'KeyTime'.

Comment: You cannot do that.
At least using the default WPF tools.
When a value is set in XAML, a converter from string is looked for for the type.
The same thing happens if you set Binding.
But the elements in the resorces are referenced and  the values ​​will not be converted.
But the constructors Duration and KeyTime cannot getting string.

Comment: You can set a string in resources.
And then, where Duration or KeyTime is needed, set the Binding to this string in XAML.
The string will be automatically converted.

Comment: @EldHasp This did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly using StaticResource like

```
KeyTime="{StaticResource AnimationTime}"
```

you may often use a Binding with the resource as `Source` object like

```
KeyTime="{Binding Source={StaticResource AnimationTime}}"
```

and thus benefit from automatic type conversion.

An example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <system:String x:Key="AnimationTime">0:0:4</system:String>

    <Storyboard x:Key="ExampleStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation To="1"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            Duration="{Binding Source={StaticResource AnimationTime}}"/>

        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                KeyTime="{Binding Source={StaticResource AnimationTime}}"
                Value="{x:Static Brushes.Green}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="Red" Opacity="0">
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard
                Storyboard="{StaticResource ExampleStoryboard}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is the above working for you? I am getting the correct output, but the times are just ignored and set to whatever the default for their types is. You can see this most clearly by just setting the TimeSpan to e.g. 20 seconds. It also comes with numerous errors in the output along the lines of...

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.TimeSpan' and 'System.Windows.Duration'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='TimeSpan' (HashCode=40000000); target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=26987408); target property is 'Duration' (type 'Duration')

Comment: However, changing system:TimeSpan to a system:String, as recommended by @EldHasp worked.

Comment: Tested both String and TimeSpan, unfortunately with a short time only, and didn't realize that TimeSpan did not actually work. Changed to String.